# Convolution 1D signals on log grid with python

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signal-processing

i have two time series discretized on log10 timestamps which i want to convolve with one another, using python. For linearly spaced time series i use `scipy.signal.convole`, which works just fine. Is there something similar for log10 discretization? The cut-off frequency is defined in terms of the standard deviation of the Gauss Kernel (sigma). The goal is to filter the log with the same cut-off frequency.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sg

f = lambda t : np.sin(2 * t) + np.sin(0.5 * t)

sigma = 1
kernel = lambda x : np.exp(-x**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma)


# LINEAR DISCRETIZATION

t_linear = np.arange(0, 100, 0.01)
signal_linearly_discretized = f(t_linear)

t_kernel_linear = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
kernel_linearly_discretized = kernel(t_kernel_linear)


# Filter by convolution of kernel and signal

signal_filtered_linear = np.convolve(kernel_linearly_discretized, signal_linearly_discretized,
                              mode="same") / np.sum(kernel_linearly_discretized)


# LOG DISCRETIZATION

t_log = np.logspace(0, 100, 1000)
signal_log_discretized = f(t_log)

"""
Filtering signal_log_discretized is unclear
"""

# Filter by convolution of kernel and signal

signal_filtered_linear = np.convolve(kernel_linearly_discretized, signal_linearly_discretized,
                              mode="same") / np.sum(kernel_linearly_discretized)

# Plotting of linear signal and filtered signal

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t_linear, signal_linearly_discretized)
ax.set_title("signal")

ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(t_linear, signal_filtered_linear)
ax.set_title("signal filtered")

fig.tight_layout()
```

Above you can see the code that i would use to apply a Gauss filter to a linearly discretized signal. I want to perform the same (or a comparable) operation on the signal `signal_log_discretized`.

Thanks

Comment: Please, add a reproducible data sample and the code/s you tried so far

Comment: i hope that the code i added above makes things a bit more clear. Thanks